# Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.soapharness.SOAPClient

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm getting the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class class com.test.soapharness.SOAPClient
```

When I execute my run.bat. Below is the code I have written for run.bat:

```
setlocal
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73"
set CLASSPATH=.;TestHarness.jar;lib\*
set JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="./config/ssl-server.truststore" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=Password01

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp %CLASSPATH% com.test.soapharness.SOAPClient
endlocal
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Show class `com.test.soapharness.SOAPClient`

Comment: That's what it says. No magic there. You're missing jar with class file in classpath. Print classpath from runtime  if such exception happens like `(UrlClassloader) getClass.getClassloader().getUrls`. You can also get class from classloader like `getClass().getClassloader().getResource('com/test/soapharness/SOAPClient.class')`

Comment: @Jens The class has a main.

Comment: @deathangel908 the class com.test.soapharness.SOAPClient is a java file located in src. Why will it look for that in a jar?

Comment: @Ekta mybe. But Show the code please.

Comment: @Etka, well  `cust.temenos.soapharness` and `com.test.soapharness` are different packages. CLass with the same name in different packages is **NOT** the same class. Please edit your question, so you don't confuse people, or check if you've been looking for a wrong class.

Comment: You may check if your _TestHarness.jar_ contains required class file `SOAPClient.class` (in the correct directory/package). Simply change _.jar_ to _.zip_ and open the file. Maybe, your build is wrong. Also you question is probably wrong, since the error complains about `cust.temenos.soapharness.SOAPClient`, but your batch clearly calls `com.test.soapharness.SOAPClient`.